# Installing both Fuerte and Electric

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I'm getting crazy with ROS/Ubuntu versions, on my laptop I installed Ubuntu 11.10 because I had to work on a university project written for ROS Electric, now (for another exam) I should install a stack called dvo_slam that is hard to install on Electric (I guess it's designed with Fuerte in mind). So my first thought has been to install Ubuntu 12.04 as a virtual machine on top of 11.10 and run Fuerte in it (horrible! ain't it?), then I found this link:

http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#fuerte-turtle-mar-2012

there it's stated that Fuerte can run also on 11.10 so my question is: can I install also Fuerte on my OS? Is it a mess??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78751/installing-both-fuerte-and-electric/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2013-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can. Why should it be a mess?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1